# ASP.Net MVC jQuery UI MultiSelect MultiSelectFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am having a problem with the jQuery multiselect plugin.
Essentially I have a partial view which renders and is hidden when the page is loaded.
Within the partial view I have the following code defined in a script section:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlCountries').multiselect().multiselectfilter();
    var countries = $('#ddlCountries');
    var parent = $("#ddlCountries").parent();
    var span = $("#ddlCountries").parent().find("span[class='custom-select-back']");
    debugger;
```

This code selects a dropdown list and applies the multiselect plugin - along with the filter options. Everything is fine with one exception - once the partial is displayed a span object with a class of "custom-select-back" is rendered over the top meaning I cannot use the control.
Code used in other parts of the system simply selects the parent of the dropdown and hides the span as can be seen above - Unfortunately in this case that code does not work.
If I inspect the source at the point the debugger is hit the parent of ddlCountries is the parent DIV - the span doesn't exist at this stage.
If I inspect the source after the page has finished loading, the parent is an element custom-select object which now contains the problematic span.

I need to somehow hide this span but I cannot see how or where I can do this. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in Jsfiddle and share it here?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I could not resolve this using jQuery/javascript as DOM elements simply did not exist at the the point the code executed.
I instead used CSS to hide the element (display:none) when it was eventually added.